# C# Volley how to get OnResponse?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-volley

Please let me know where do I need to write "OnResponse" in C# using Volley.

I converted the code from Android studio to c# which uses Volley library. Then I opened the code in Xamarin to send request and receive the response.I added the Volley Nuget package (Xamarin.Bindings.Volley).
Following is the code snippet of converted C#. However, The code do not recognize "OnResponse" function. I need an example of Successful "OnResponse" implementation in c# using Volley.

```
    public void GetAndPostReqquest(string url, int requestedCode, JSONObject @object, IServerResponse jsonResponse)
    {
        int method = Request.equestMethodConsts.Get;
        switch (requestedCode)
        {
            case POST:
                method = Request.equestMethodConsts.Post;
                break;
            case PUT:
                method = Request.equestMethodConsts.Put;
                break;

        }


        if (!IsInternetAvailable())
        {
            jsonResponse.RequestFinishedWithError(MContext.GetString(App8.Droid.Resource.String.internet_connection_is_not_available));
            return;
        }


        jsonResponse.RequestStarted();


        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(method, url, @object, Llistener, EerrorListener) { 

        private void OnResponse(JSONObject response)
        {
            IDictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            string credentials = UNAME + ":" + PWD;
            string auth = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(credentials.ToCharArray(0, credentials.Length));
            headers["Authorization"] = auth;
            headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            //return headers;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use Volley on your code you will need to do a couple of small changes.

First, I would suggest you change the Nugget package you are using from **Xamarin.Bindings.Volley** to the **Xamarin.Android.Volley**. The one you are currently using is outdated (2017) and the one I am suggesting not only is up-to-date but also is maintained by Xamarin, so chances are that it will be always updated.

In the `Activity` where your code is being executed, you will need to make it implement two interfaces that are part of `Volley` namespace, these are: `Response.IListener` and `Response.IErrorListener`

It should look like this:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity, Response.IListener, Response.IErrorListener
```

This will require you to complete the implementation of these interfaces by adding two methods: `public void OnErrorResponse(VolleyError p0)` and `public void OnResponse(Object p0)` to the **Activity** class

In the `OnResponse` method is where you are gonna add your logic.

You will need to cast the `Object` received in the `OnResponse` to a `JSONObject` object before using it.

The `Activity` definition should later look like this:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity, Response.IListener, Response.IErrorListener
{
    public void OnErrorResponse(VolleyError p0)
    {
    }

    public void OnResponse(Object p0)
    {
        if(p0 is JSONObject response)
        {
            // Do your logic here with response
        }
    }

   /......

}
```

Your request will be updated like this:

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(method, url, @object, this, this);
```

Hope this helps.-

Comment: this is working to some extent. However, my c# Request class is written in a different file and I do not have the authority to change the architecture.

Comment: So, I was looking for how to implement the thing,i.e. the function "OnResponse" as you have rightly suggested, in a separate c# class (and then call it in the activity class)?

Comment: That's right @humbledog . You can implement the OnResponse on another class and pass in an instance of this class when creating the JsonObjectRequest object

Comment: from that external class, I can not call like "JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(method, url, &#64;object, this, this);". Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: My Bad Formatting, it will be "@" instead of "&#64;" in the above comment. "&#64;" is the HTML code for at the rate which has not been reflected above.

Comment: It helped me solving the problem.